# Unable To Bridge Two Teamed Interfaces - Advice?

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, bridge, network-interface

Before the wall of code I'll explain the situation. I'm trying to set up two interfaces to be teamed together, and from that team create a bridge.

I've been studying for the RHCE and I believe this type of situation might be on the test so I've been trying to get it down, however in all of my testing I've not been able to get this to work properly. At the end of the set up, the bridge appears to be there, however there is no IP assigned to it, and it is unable to ping the gateway.

The test environments are vm's in kvm and I've been using internal networks.

```
Starting Interfaces

4: ens10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: ens11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7c:68:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Creating Team w/ ens10 & ens11

  nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config '{"runner": {"name": "activebackup"}}'
  Connection 'team0' (75299245-c21f-4bfc-8c21-1728378d5a33) successfully added.

  nmcli con add type team-slave con-name team0-port1 ifname ens10 master team0 Connection 'team0-port1' (68ee3568-bb1d-4f66-a2a2-31ea756da2f4) successfully added.

  nmcli con add type team-slave con-name team0-port2 ifname ens11 master team0 Connection 'team0-port2' (0569a1de-2280-4087-b026-2e22afc11c79) successfully added.


  teamdctl team0 state
  setup:
    runner: activebackup
  ports:
    ens10
      link watches:
        link summary: up
        instance[link_watch_0]:
          name: ethtool
          link: up
    ens11
      link watches:
        link summary: up
        instance[link_watch_0]:
          name: ethtool
          link: up
  runner:
    active port: ens10

  6: team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.136/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic team0
         valid_lft 3460sec preferred_lft 3460sec
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe60:2623/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

  Teamed Interface Pinging Gateway

  ping -I team0 192.168.100.1

  PING 192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1) from 192.168.100.136 team0: 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.703 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.253 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.239 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=0.240 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=0.290 ms ^C
  --- 192.168.100.1 ping statistics ---
  15 packets transmitted, 6 received, 60% packet loss, time 14000ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.239/0.328/0.703/0.168 ms


Bridge Setup

  yum install -y bridge-utils

  systemctl disable NetworkManager
  rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service'
  rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.service'
  rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'

  systemctl stop NetworkManager

  echo 'BRIDGE=brteam0' >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0
  cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0

  DEVICE=team0
  TEAM_CONFIG="{\"runner\": {\"name\": \"activebackup\"}}"
  DEVICETYPE=Team
  BOOTPROTO=dhcp
  DEFROUTE=yes
  PEERDNS=yes
  PEERROUTES=yes
  IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
  IPV6INIT=yes
  IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
  IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
  IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
  IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
  IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
  NAME=team0
  UUID=75299245-c21f-4bfc-8c21-1728378d5a33
  ONBOOT=yes
  BRIDGE=brteam0


  cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0-port1

  NAME=team0-port1
  UUID=68ee3568-bb1d-4f66-a2a2-31ea756da2f4
  DEVICE=ens10
  ONBOOT=yes
  TEAM_MASTER=team0
  DEVICETYPE=TeamPort

  cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0-port2

  NAME=team0-port2
  UUID=0569a1de-2280-4087-b026-2e22afc11c79
  DEVICE=ens11
  ONBOOT=yes
  TEAM_MASTER=team0
  DEVICETYPE=TeamPort

  cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-brteam0

  DEVICE=team0
  ONBOOT=yes
  TYPE=Bridge
  IPADDR0=192.168.100.100
  PREFIX0=24



  systemctl restart network


Bridge Interface Stays Down With No IP?

  4: ens10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master team0 state UP qlen 1000
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe60:2623/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  5: ens11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master team0 state UP qlen 1000
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe7c:68d0/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  7: team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brteam0 state UP
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe60:2623/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  8: brteam0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Turn Up Interface And Still No IP?

  ip link set brteam0 up

  4: ens10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master team0 state UP qlen 1000
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe60:2623/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  5: ens11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master team0 state UP qlen 1000
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe7c:68d0/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  7: team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brteam0 state UP
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe60:2623/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  8: brteam0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
      link/ether 52:54:00:60:26:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe60:2623/64 scope link
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Bridge Shows Active Interfaces?

  brctl show

  bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
  brteam0         8000.525400602623       no              team0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You may want to remove the ip parameters (BOOTPROTO,...) from ifcfg-team0 since they are now defined in ifcfg-brteam0.

   ifcfg-team0 could be as short as:

   ```
   DEVICE=team0
   TEAM_CONFIG="{\"runner\": {\"name\": \"activebackup\"}}"
   DEVICETYPE=Team
   NAME=team0
   UUID=75299245-c21f-4bfc-8c21-1728378d5a33
   ONBOOT=yes
   BRIDGE=brteam0
   ```
2. In ifcfg-brteam0, the DEVICE value should be modified, e.g.:

   ```
   DEVICE=brteam0
   ```

   instead of team0 in the OP, value already used by ifcfg-team0.